# Kill javascript engine in webview for chrome app

Tags: google-chrome-app, google-chrome-webview

Is it possible to terminate the javascript engine in a webview that runs from a chrome app on the desktop, using the chrome aps api (and not the java api).

I see there is a [terminate method](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/tags/webview#method-terminate) on the webview, but it seems to also kill the render function and I would only stop/freeze the javascript running there.